# How to add padding/margin in bar in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to ask how to add margin on a specific datasets/group-bar in [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)? (like the picture below). Here is the [chartjs-playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-darkness-x31u7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/index.js) wherein I check my output.

Here is my current work:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
     maxBarThickness: 30,
    categoryPercentage: 0.65,
  }],
 };
```

*The first and last datasets has different margins*
[image]